# Написание простенького софта работающего с mysql

Tags: c#, c++, mysql, c, delphi

Есть задача: написать для фирмы программку, работающую с mysql 5.1 
Фирма маленькая нанять спеца не можем.

**Нужна помощь с выбором инструмента.**
Пояснение. Сам не программист, но вникать умею. Когда-то давно программировал. Небольшой опыт и понимание происходящего имеется.
Вот что я смог нарыть сам:

а) Delphi ->   отсутствует (кривая?) поддержка unicode(помню как-то мучался с каким-то компонентом, в упор не понимающим кириллицу - остались неприятные воспоминания, то есть -, синтаксис +/-, платность -. Верно или что-то изменилось со времен Delphi 7?

б) -- Си -> Думаю ближе подойдёт "по духу", но смущает поддержка IDE и mysql и GUI - почитал, что самый няшный (Имхо) CODE::BLOCKS под Win не любит mysql и gui (например GTK) - обречение гемороя вместо удовольствия.
Какие тут варианты? Либо писать спокойно на линухе..а потом..переносить на win? Или отладить компилер и компоновщик на windows? (Сам на win и программа исключительно под Win)

в) C++ / C# 
Не знаю этих бородатых совершенно, при слове "ООП" становится страшно, да и не знаю, где найти столько времени, чтобы раздуплить эти жуткие штуки, хотя эти_ваши_интернеты отсылают меняподобных в WindowsForms или а-ля.

Как быть/как жить?

Помогите заблудшему страннику. Да прибудет с Вами сила.

Comment: С помощью C# вы решите свою проблему чисто мышкой  :)

Comment: Ну если вы знаете Delphi, то в C# разберетесь наверняка, практически один язык, особенно с учетом того, что создавались они одним и тем же человеком. Есть конечно и от C в нем, например Begin - End заменили на { }

Comment: Почему именно MySql, почему не бесплатная версия SQL Server? Тогда можно было бы в два счета в Visual Studio написать обработчик для БД (не важно, хоть на C#, хоть на VB).

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya не переманивайте человека на тёмную сторону (SQL Server). Выбрал MySQL, пускай на этом и остаётся - популярнейшая опенсорсная БД.

Comment: @zed: Самый популярный — не значит самый лучший. Вот у нас самый популярный тег PHP здесь наверняка.

Comment: @zed, расскажите "темному" человеку про "светлые" стороны недо-бд ;) Опенсорсные продукты ни когда не станут самыми стабильными и самыми надежными, так что намек на использование MS-SQL в редакции скажем Express, самый разумный

Comment: Я рекомендую подумать о продукте, если это две формы с несколькими гридами, так походит как `Delphi` так и `C#`. Но если что то посложнее - рекомендую подумать, стоит сейчас городить огород чтобы через месяц(год) наплодить костылей и потом все переписать с нуля. Или взять знающего человека, который сможет заложить правильный фундамент для дальнейшей разработки и на основе него сформировать правильное архитектурное решение. Реализовывал проекты в связке `Delphi` + `MySQL` и все работало на ура. Если думать о перспективе - `Delphi` программистов все меньше и меньше.

Comment: @VladD А я и не говорю, что MySQL - самая лучшая, она популярная и проста в обращении. И есть подозрение, что для задач топикстартера её хватит за глаза. А лучшей я считаю PostgreSQL.

Comment: @Dmitry Простите, но вы говорите какую-то несусветную чушь про опен-сорс.

Comment: @zed: Вы аргументировали тем, что MySQL популярна. Мне кажется, лучшим аргументом было бы описать в двух словах её преимущества (для задачи ТС).

Comment: @VladD Так а какое преимущество у MS-SQL? То, что с ней из Visual Studio проще работать (именно этот аргумент прозвучал)? Ну а я могу сказать, что преимущество у MySQL это то, что она может работать на Linux и её проще администрировать. Мне кажется тут холиварить бессмысленно, поскольку мы не знаем реальных требований к БД и отговаривать топикстартера от выбранной БД ради удобства разработки на C# как-то не правильно.

Comment: @zed: Я не специалист по БД, поэтому мне интересно узнать преимущества той или иной базы. Лёгкая интеграция с языком/средой разработки — это, несомненно, важное преимущество. Но наверняка у SQL Server есть и другие преимущества, о них расскажут те, кто знает. А какие преимущества у MySQL кроме работы на линуксе? (Это не ирония, мне действительно интересно.)

Comment: @zed простите, но тоже самое могу сказать в ответ, и даже аргументировать. С кого вы спросите если у вас украдут данные например? Или загнется ваша бд? Ну или на худой конец крякнут ваш линукс? А ну да, можно же на сисадмина повесить... Опенсорс зло, поверти...

Comment: Вы предлагаете выбрать инструмент за вас, полагаясь на описание задачи без контекста. Очевидно, что никто не может угадать, на чем же вам будет проще решить задачу. Ответы будут полностью зависеть от предпочтений отвечающих. Подобные вопросы - оффтопик на SO.

Answer (score 1):

Посоветую взять Delphi, тем более что у вас есть какой-никакой опыт работы с ней.

Проблем с юникодом в современных версиях (начиная с Delphi 2009) нету, из коробки есть компонент для работы с СУБД (FireDac), но можно взять и сторонний ZeosLib. Интернеты пестрят туториалами: http://mirsovetov.net/delphi-connect-mysql.html

Если Delphi по каким-то причинам не устроит, то запасным вариантом можно считать C#.

Comment: зачем доставать мертвеца из могилы? им же не только писать но и поддерживать придется

Comment: @zed Рад что туториал писал не зря и хоть кому то он пригодился. :-)

Comment: @Dmitry Каждая жаба хвалит свое болото ;-)

Comment: @Dmitry Имхо, для описанной задачи и исходных условий, Delphi является оптимальным вариантом, чтобы там про него не говорили злые языки.

Comment: @zed, задачи как таковой в топике нет. Если вы возьметесь написать то - не знаю что, да еще и непонятно на чем, то вы маг...